# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a line of PHP code for which I am getting an error.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

The line of code is the **60<sup>th</sup>** line in my program,

Here's a link to the complete PHP code:

http://rancorous-rsps.com/SQL.java

I am getting the following error message:

> Warning: `mysql_fetch_array()` expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ranco690/public_html/highscores/index.php

Comment: When `mysql_query()` gets an error it returns `false`. Echo `mysql_error()` to see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your query `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Ratio ORDER BY Kills DESC LIMIT 20");` must be incorrect. Check if you have tables `Ration`, column `Kills`.
You need to test `$result` before proceeding.

For example:

```
if ( $result )
{
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
      echo $row['playerName'];
      echo "<br />";
   }
   mysql_free_result($result);
}
else
   die( mysql_error()) ;
```

As you could notice, I added `mysql_free_result($result);` which you do not have.

Also `ranco690_kill` database may be improperly spelled.
Try this:

```
mysql_select_db("ranco690_kill", $con) || die( "ranco690_kill does not exist." ) ;
```

Blessings,
Greg.

Comment: Selecting from an empty table doesn't cause an error, it just means the while loop will run 0 times.

Comment: @Barmar: You are right! It has to be incorrect query then. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

For a start you should be wrapping it in an 'if' make sure that results is a resource.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Ratio ORDER BY Kills DESC LIMIT 20");

if ( $result ) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['playerName'];
        echo "<br />";
    }
} else {
    // there is a problem ...
    echo mysql_error(); // display error so you can fix it
}
```